# Wpf textbox text bind to viewmodel property and resource property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a wpf text box which is styled using a resource and the text value for the textbox comes from the style resource using a converter.

This is a part of the code from the style resource file. It is part of the control template for the textbox style.

```
     <Style x:Key="DateTimePickerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

//Other code omitted for clarity
    <ToggleButton 
        Template="{StaticResource Button}"
        MaxHeight="21"
        Width="130" 
        IsEnabled="True"
        Name="ImageButton"
        Grid.Column="0" 
        IsChecked="False"
        >
        <ToggleButton.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeConverter}" >
                <Binding 
                    ElementName="CalendarDisplay" Path="SelectedDate" Mode="TwoWay"></Binding>
                <Binding 
                    ElementName="ComboBox" Path="SelectedValue" Mode="TwoWay"></Binding>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ToggleButton.Content>
    </ToggleButton>
    </Style>
```

I connect the style resource in the code behind like this:

```
 TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                Style styleCalendar = (Style) tb.TryFindResource("DateTimePickerStyle");

                if (styleCalendar != null)
                {
                    DatePickerEndDate.Style = styleCalendar;//DateTimePickerEndDate is a text box on xaml
                }
```

I am using this style on another window to style a textbox but want it to bind to a property in the viewmodel.

```
<TextBox 
    Name="ClickNowEndDate" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Width="200"
    Text="{Binding ClickNowEndDateTime}"
    />
```

My question is there any way by which the above textbox displays the value from the converter in the style resource and at the same time, I can retrive its value in the view model using the "ClickNowEndDateTime" property.

Comment: Your question is unclear , cant see any connection between ToggleButton and TextBox.

Comment: The textbox in the xaml takes the style from the resource. I have edited the quiestion to make it clearer.